# How to launch a thread without waiting for response in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, handle

There is a CreateThread() call within a for loop, and I want all the threads to be launched one after another and each thread writes data to a object.

```
      `$while (ii != mapOServs.end())
{
      Array_of_Thread_Handles[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,MyThread, &args[i] , 0 , NULL);
    }
```

But the threads don't start until it hits WaitForMultipleObjects or WaitForSingleObject.

How do I make all the threads run one after another without waiting for a response?

Also, what is the best object to use so that it can be modified by different threads at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The threads are indeed "started" immediately --- Windows will create the necessary internal structures, allocate the stack and so forth, and add them to the scheduler's run list. However, they won't necessarily be **scheduled** immediately.

In particular, the thread doing the launching will likely keep running until it has used up its time slice. If you have more threads running than processor cores (including threads in other processes), then your new threads may well not be scheduled on a processor for a while, and your thread doing the launching may execute up to a synchronization call such as `WaitForSingleObject` before any of them have had a chance to do any work.

Answer (score 4):

The threads do in fact all start immediately. You can write to any data structure from the threads so long as you correctly synchronize access to that structure.

Comment: they start, however may not actually start running straight after the CreateThread function, because the task scheduler can keep the main thread running and only run the threads after a while.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are stuck while debugging. When you step-over `CreateThread` it may not immediately create and run the thread, since you are *debugging* at the point. 
Remember, while actively debugging the code, only one thread is allowed to run, all other threads remain suspended. When you hit F10 or F11, the debugger gives debuggee to run, which is eventually asks OS to run process/threads to execute. I may add more, but your question demands more clarification.

Comment: You are right, I am stuck in debugging. I was wondering why the other threads did not run and display their messages while I was debugging one thread.